# GWT expenses demo in STS?

Tags: gwt, sample, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

After hunting around a lot and trying different builds and versions of sts i still cannot get the expenses sample to run from within sts. I have managed to run it using mvn ; but not using sts.
the expenses demo uses gae < i am a newbie to gwt and gae> and i am trying to run the sample in demo mode.
. sts fresh install
. gwt 2.2
. gwt designer beta
. google eclipse plugin
. import samples/expenses from gwt2.2 as an existing mvn project
. run as web application ( first /loadexpensdb.html )

i have run into quite a few different errors including file access permissions to the .txt files for loading data ( and then moving them to the top folder ; the same location as the pom.xml ) ; data-nucleus duplicate resource registration ; amongst others.

my question is this : is the expenses demo a roo (+data nucleus) only project ? can i not simply import it and run it in development mode in sts ? am i missing an understanding of how gae runs in dev or hosted mode ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did, using STS 2.6SR1 and ROO 1.1.3

- start roo, execute command script expenses.roo
- exit roo
- mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
- start STS, import the project
- in roo, issue this: dependency add --groupId com.google.appengine --artifactId appengine-api-1.0-sdk --version 1.4.3
- check if in project properties / google the app engine option is checked in. if you are using the maven version, be sure to follow instructions here:

  - http://juergen.kuster.cc/blog/2011/01/20/m2eclipse-gae-in-eclipse-3-5/
- run as web application

HTH